# Exception on ActionResult when retrieving DateTime object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, google-calendar-api

I'm doing a project in asp.net mvc that will connect to Google Calendar API. In a view, I have a form with several inputs which will create an Event object. However, when pressing the submit button, this exception appears:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'eve_start_date' of 
non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' from method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Page(...)'
```

but I'm filling the eve_start_date input, and I don't know why the exception appears

This is my form:

```
<form method="post">
    Titulo:<input type="text" id="eve_title" />
    <br />
    Descripción:<input type="text" id="eve_desc" />
    <br />
    Fecha Inicio:<input type="datetime-local" id="eve_start_date" />
    <br />
    Fecha Fin:<input type="datetime-local" id="eve_end_date" />
    <br />
...
   <input type="submit" title="Submit" />
</form>
```

and this the Post Method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Page(String eve_title, String eve_desc, DateTime eve_start_date, DateTime eve_end_date, ...)
    {
    Event newEvent = new Event();
    newEvent.Summary = eve_title;
    newEvent.Description = eve_desc;
    // Converting datetime to eventdatetime
    newEvent.Start = Calendar_Methods.ToEventDateTime(eve_start_date);
    newEvent.End = Calendar_Methods.ToEventDateTime(eve_end_date);
    ...
    return View();
}
```

but the method doesn't even start because of the Exception, and I'm not sure what could I do to fix it. I tried adding ? after the paramers type `DateTime? eve_start_date` but an error appears saying that I cant convert `System.DateTime?` to `System.DateTime`, so I undid that, but there is a `DateTime` that sometimes will be null, so how can I indicate that field is nullable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use `name` instead of `id` for your form, add name for all input tag in form like this `<input type="datetime-local" name="eve_start_date" />`

```
<form method="post">
    Titulo:<input type="text" id="eve_title" />
    <br />
    Descripción:<input type="text" name="eve_desc" />
    <br />
    Fecha Inicio:<input type="datetime-local" name="eve_start_date" />
    <br />
    Fecha Fin:<input type="datetime-local" name="eve_end_date" />
    <br />
...
   <input type="submit" title="Submit" />
</form>
```

Update: you change parameter from  `DateTime eve_start_date` to `DateTime? eve_start_date` and check null

```
if (eve_start_date != null) {
     newEvent.Start = Calendar_Methods.ToEventDateTime(eve_start_date.Value);
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! And what would I have to do to receive a Null DateTime??

Comment: You can set DateTime? eve_start_date

Comment: use need use eve_start_date.Value